# TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded, How do I find the DOM parentelement on signup page pop up so element can be clickable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, puppeteer

I'm creating a script to create accounts on the Doordash website and I'm having a hard time finding the parent element so the First Name box can be clicked on for puppeteer to type. The elements I've tried are

`dov[class="Input__InputRoot-sc-1ips7db-0 gFCNhg"]`,
`div[class="Input__InputContainer-sc-1ips7db-1 iRiSUV"]`,
`div[class="Input__InputContentContainer-sc-1ips7db-2 gdVwGJ"]`,
`input[class="Input__InputContent-sc-1ips7db-3 cKdRiq"]`

None have been successful elements that were clickable, so I thought I'd shoot my shot on stackoverflow to see if anyone more familiarized with DOMs to help me find the one I'm in need of using. If anyone has any ideas, please let me know. This is the website for those who want to access it to see themselves - https://www.doordash.com/

[image: Doordash Site]

```
const { Discord, CommandInteraction, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const fs = require('fs');
const generator = require('generate-password');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
const Ua = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-anonymize-ua');
const prompt = require("prompt-sync")({ sigint: true });
const util = require('util');
const request = require('request')
const wait = require('node:timers/promises').setTimeout;
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
puppeteer.use(Ua());




//------------------ Proxy Integration ------------------//
    var proxyData = "proxies.json";
            function getProxies() {
                if (fs.existsSync(proxyData)) {
                    return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(proxyData));
                }

            var proxies = {
                proxies: prompt("Input Proxy List Separated By Commas: ")?.split(/,\s*/) ?? [],
                proxyUsername: prompt("Input Proxy Username: "),
                proxyPassword: prompt("Input Proxy Password: ")
            };

            fs.writeFileSync(proxyData, JSON.stringify(proxies));

            return proxies [Math.floor(Math.random() * proxies.length)];
        }
            let { proxies, proxyUsername, proxyPassword } = getProxies();

            let proxyList = (`${proxies[Math.floor(Math.random() * proxies.length)]}`);




//------------------ Password Generator ------------------//
    var doordashPassword = generator.generate({
        length: 12,
        numbers: true,
        symbols: true,
        exclude: ':, *, (, ), ~, -, _, =, +, ., /, ?, |,{, }, ;'
    });



//------------------ First & Last Names ------------------//
    
    
        const nameData = "names.json";
        function getNames() {
            if (fs.existsSync(nameData)) {
                return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(nameData));
            }

        var names = {
        firstNames: prompt("Input Comma Separated Names:")?.split(/,\s*/) ?? [],
        lastNames: prompt("Input Comma Separated Names:")?.split(/,\s*/) ?? []
        };

        fs.writeFileSync(nameData, JSON.stringify(names));

        return names [Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
        }
        let { firstNames, lastNames } = getNames(); 

//------------------ Phone Numbers ------------------//
    
    
const phoneData = "numbers.json";
function getPhone() {
    if (fs.existsSync(phoneData)) {
        return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(phoneData));
    }

var phone = {
    phoneNumbers: prompt("Input Comma Separated Phone Numbers:")?.split(/,\s*/) ?? []
};

fs.writeFileSync(phoneData, JSON.stringify(phone));

return phone [Math.floor(Math.random() * phone.length)];
}
let { phoneNumbers } = getPhone(); 



module.exports = {
    name: 'doordash',
    description: 'Generate Doordash Account',
    permission: 'USE_APPLICATION_COMMANDS',
    options: [
        {
            name: 'catchall',
            description: 'Input Account Email.',
            required: true,
            type: 'STRING'
        }
    ],

    /**
     * 
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction 
     */
    async execute(interaction) {

        const { options } = interaction;
        let catchall = options.getString("catchall");
        let accountEmail = (`${firstNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * firstNames.length)]}` + `${lastNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length)]}` + `@` + `${catchall}`);
        let accountPhone = (`${phoneNumbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * phoneNumbers.length)]}`)
        let accountPassword = doordashPassword;

        await interaction.deferReply();
        await wait(1000);


        const signupBtn = `a[class="sc-fa656bdf-0 ieEwNI styles__StyledButtonRoot-sc-1ldytso-0 eJISjd"]`
        const firstName = `<div class="Input__InputContentContainer-sc-1ips7db-2 gdVwGJ"> <input class="Input__InputContent-sc-1ips7db-3 cKdRiq"> </div>`

try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
            headless: false,
            executablePath: `C:/Program Files/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Application/brave.exe`,
            userDataDir: `%LOCALAPPDATA%/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/User Data/Default`,

            args: [
                '--no-sandbox',
                '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
                '--disable-web-security',
                '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process',
                `--enable-auto-reload=true`,
                `--proxy-server=http://${proxyList}`
                ],
            })

            const page = await browser.newPage()
            await page.authenticate({username:proxyUsername, password:proxyPassword});
            await page.goto("https://www.doordash.com/")


            await page.waitForSelector(signupBtn, { visible: true });
            await Promise.all([
                page.click(signupBtn),
                page.waitForNavigation()
            ]);

            await page.waitForSelector(firstName, { visible: true })
            await page.focus(firstName)
            await page.click(firstName)
            await page.keyboard.type(`${firstNames}`)
            await page.keyboard.press("Tab");
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of these class names seem to be generated dynamically and will quite certainly break next time the app is deployed.

However some semantical properties are bound to stay, like "IdentitySignupFirstNameField".

Also note that when accessing elements you need to specify not their HTML code, but CSS selectors for those elements:

```
const signupBtn = `a[class="sc-fa656bdf-0 ieEwNI styles__StyledButtonRoot-sc-1ldytso-0 eJISjd"]`;
const firstName = `input[data-anchor-id="IdentitySignupFirstNameField"]`;
```

**Update**: just noticed that the signup form exists in an iFrame.

You cannot access items within an iFrame using `page`, since technically that is a separate page, so you need to check all child pages (frames) to find the necessary one. Like this (code not tested):

```
// ...
let signupPage;

await page.waitForSelector(signupBtn, { visible: true });
await Promise.all([
  page.click(signupBtn),
  page.waitForNavigation(),
]);

for (const frame of page.mainFrame().childFrames()) {
  if (frame.url().includes('identity.doordash.com')) {
    console.log('Found the signup/login frame');
    signupPage = frame;
    break;
  }
}

if (!signupPage) {
  throw new Error('Signup frame still not found!');
}

await signupPage.waitForSelector(firstName, { visible: true });
await signupPage.focus(firstName);
await signupPage.click(firstName);

// and so on
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I just tried "input[data-anchor-id="IdentitySignupFirstNameField"]" but no luck, puppeteer was still unable to click it.

Comment: is that for the first name box? I already found the selector to where it'll open up the sign up button frame, but I can't find a valid selector that'll click the first name box

Comment: Yes, it's for the first name. Please, read the update carefully